# SQL C# Interface - SQL loading data filled with extra spaces

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table UserTable with a field name varchar(20).   I have an edit screen that has the data binding set up to bind to UserTable.name.   The problem is that when I am editing it, the field has the value followed by spaces up to a length of 20.  As a result, the user enters the field and tries to, for instance, add an s to the end of his name, the user interface complains because the field is full already.  How can I get the database to not add those extra spaces.

Here is the code to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[US_usertable](
    [user_name] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [password] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [departmentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [employeeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [emailaddress] [nchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_US_usertable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [employeeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the query in the table adapter:

```
SELECT emailaddress, employeeID, departmentID, user_name, password FROM us_usertable WHERE (employeeID = @empID)
```

Comment: One way would be to "Trim" the results.  Your solution depends upon what technology is being used to bind.  Search the web for examples.  ASP.NET has a solution - using Entity Framework or nHibernate has a different solution.  A quick and dirty way (and not suitable for Production code) is to rtrim right in the SQL statement - this adds I/O overhead to the query but it'll "get'r done."

Comment: Weird this is usally the behavior of char(size) columns not varchar(size) ones

Comment: It's the `nchar` that you're having trouble with, yes?  Try an `nvarchar` instead.

Comment: It's the varchar -- I will try nvarchar  -- Tried it -- no luck.

Comment: You should be using `NVarchar` for human-readable text; not `Varchar` and not `nchar`, but the code you posted does not have the behavior you described; it's something else you're doing. Post the code that “has the data binding set up”.

Comment: Are you sure that this field has always been a field of varchar type?. If you initially create it as char(20) add data to it and then change it to varchar(20) the extra spaces added when the column was of fixed size are not automatically removed from the existing data while new records will not be filled to the field size with spaces

Comment: You guys rock it!!!   You were right -- it was in my Visual Studio generated code.  It had defined it as char and not varchar.  Thank you so, so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Visual Studio generated code, it defined name as char.  When I did a search through the entire project, I was able to see that and change it to varchar in the four or five places it appeared.   When I tested the code again, it worked the way it was supposed to.